# authlogic i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, authlogic

Is it possible to i18n-ize authlogic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authlogic already supports i18n, see the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/I18n):

> Module: Authlogic::I18n [...] allows any message in Authlogic to use internationalization.